# How can I write a unittest to check that a django model form is valid?

Tags: django-forms

I am trying to test that a model form is valid.

In the test function, I create the two models that feature in my custom form. I add the data to fill the form's required fields.

When I run the tests and call `is_valid()` on the form, the test fails and the form gives the error that the option that I have added is `not one of the available choices`. This suggests to me that I have incorrectly added the `Option` instance to the form or to the test. I am unsure how.

How can I make the model form valid for the test?

**tests.py**

```
    def test_valid_data(self):
        question_1 = Question(
            question_text='What is the width of the telephone?',
            date_published=timezone.now(),
            collection=Collection.objects.create()
        )
        question_1.save()
        option_1 = question_1.options.create(
            question=question_1,
            option_text='Five centimetres'
        )
        option_1.save()
        data = {'question_text': question_1.question_text, 'selected_option': option_1.option_text,}
        form = QuestionForm(data=data)
        print(form)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

**forms.py**

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selected_option'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[
                (f'{option.pk}', f'{option}')
                for option in Option.objects.filter(question_id=self.instance.pk)
            ],
            widget=RadioSelect,
            required=True,
            error_messages={
                'required': 'The question form lacks a selected_option'
            }

        )

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)
        labels = {
            'question_text': ''
        }
        widgets = {
            'question_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': '40', 'rows': '2'})
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.question_text


class Option(models.Model):
    option_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'options'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.option_text
```

Expected: `is_valid()` -> `True`

Actual:`is_valid()` -> `False`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the way that you have defined choices in `QuestionForm.__init__`:

```
choices=[
    (f'{option.pk}', f'{option}')
    for option in Option.objects.filter(question_id=self.instance.pk)
],
```

You have created `choices` based on the `pk` of the `Question` instance related with the `QuestionForm` you initiate.

In your test (and also in the admin), the `form` is not bound to any instance of `Question` when you initiate the form by entering
`form = QuestionForm(data=data)`.

Consequently, the query `Option.objects.filter(question_id=self.instance.pk)` returns `None` because `self.instance.pk` is `None`.

Therefore, you receive the error before saving the `QuestionForm` because  `choices = []`

The query would return results if you pressed the "Save" button or if you do a `form.save()`.